# Gmail Data Analysis

Tags: python, python-2.x, email

I am using Imaplib to fetch data from Gmail and get the number of emails each day. I am going to login using Imaplib twice for fetching emails for the inbox well as for the outbox (sent mail). Is it possible that I have to login only once and get result as I need?

The code works fine and I am asking for review that how I can do more optimizations with this approach.

```
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL 
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime 
from time import mktime 
from email.utils import parsedate 
import email
import pygal


address = '<Your Email>'
password = '<password>'
inbox = 'INBOX'
outbox = '[Gmail]/Sent Mail'
d = 6

def inbox_week(address,password,inbox,d):

    Monday_Tuple = ('M','o','n')
    Monday_List = []

    Tuesday_Tuple = ('T','u','e')
    Tuesday_List = []

    Wednesday_Tuple = ('W','e','d')
    Wednesday_List = []

    Thursday_Tuple = ('T','h','u')
    Thursday_List = []

    Friday_Tuple = ('F','r','i')
    Friday_List = []

    Saturday_Tuple = ('S','a','t')
    Saturday_List = []

    Sunday_Tuple = ('S','u','n')
    Sunday_List = []

    mail = IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login(address, password)
    mail.select(inbox)
    interval = (date.today()-timedelta(d)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")


    result, data =                mail.uid('search',None,'(SENTSINCE{date})'.format(date=interval))
    for num in data[0].split():

        result, data = mail.uid('fetch',num,'(RFC822)')
        msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
        msg['Date']
        main_date = msg['Date']
        Date_Tuple = main_date[0],main_date[1],main_date[2]

        if (Date_Tuple==Monday_Tuple):
            Monday_List.append(Monday_Tuple)        

        if (Date_Tuple == Tuesday_Tuple):
            Tuesday_List.append(Tuesday_Tuple)

        if (Date_Tuple == Wednesday_Tuple):
            Wednesday_List.append(Wednesday_Tuple)



        if (Date_Tuple == Thursday_Tuple):
            Thursday_List.append(Thursday_Tuple)

        if (Date_Tuple == Friday_Tuple):
            Friday_List.append(Friday_Tuple)

        if (Date_Tuple == Saturday_Tuple):
            Saturday_List.append(Saturday_Tuple)

        if (Date_Tuple == Sunday_Tuple):
            Sunday_List.append(Sunday_Tuple)


    monday_inbox = len(Monday_List)

    tuesday_inbox =  len(Tuesday_List)

    wednesday_inbox =  len(Wednesday_List)    

    thursday_inbox = len(Thursday_List)

    friday_inbox =  len(Friday_List)

    saturday_inbox =  len(Saturday_List)

    sunday_inbox =  len(Sunday_List)

    return           monday_inbox,tuesday_inbox,wednesday_inbox,thursday_inbox,friday_inbox,saturday_inbox,sunday_inbox

a,b,c,d,e,f,g = inbox_week(address,password,inbox,d)

def outbox_week(address,password,outbox,d):
    Monday_Tuple = ('M','o','n')
    Monday_List = []

    Tuesday_Tuple = ('T','u','e')
    Tuesday_List = []

    Wednesday_Tuple = ('W','e','d')
    Wednesday_List = []

    Thursday_Tuple = ('T','h','u')
    Thursday_List = []

    Friday_Tuple = ('F','r','i')
    Friday_List = []

    Saturday_Tuple = ('S','a','t')
    Saturday_List = []

    Sunday_Tuple = ('S','u','n')
    Sunday_List = []

    mail = IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login(address, password)
    mail.select(outbox)

    interval = (date.today()-timedelta(d)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
    result, data = mail.uid('search', None,'(SENTSINCE {date})'.format(date=interval))

   for num in data[0].split():

       result, data = mail.uid('fetch',num,'(RFC822)')
       msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])

       main_date = msg['Date']
       Date_Tuple = main_date[0],main_date[1],main_date[2]

       if (Date_Tuple==Monday_Tuple):
           Monday_List.append(Monday_Tuple)        

       if (Date_Tuple == Tuesday_Tuple):
           Tuesday_List.append(Tuesday_Tuple)

       if (Date_Tuple == Wednesday_Tuple):
           Wednesday_List.append(Wednesday_Tuple)



       if (Date_Tuple == Thursday_Tuple):
           Thursday_List.append(Thursday_Tuple)

       if (Date_Tuple == Friday_Tuple):
           Friday_List.append(Friday_Tuple)

       if (Date_Tuple == Saturday_Tuple):
           Saturday_List.append(Saturday_Tuple)

       if (Date_Tuple == Sunday_Tuple):
           Sunday_List.append(Sunday_Tuple)


       monday_outbox = len(Monday_List)

       tuesday_outbox =  len(Tuesday_List)

       wednesday_outbox =  len(Wednesday_List)    

       thursday_outbox = len(Thursday_List)

       friday_outbox =  len(Friday_List)

       saturday_outbox =  len(Saturday_List)

       sunday_outbox =  len(Sunday_List)

    return      monday_outbox,tuesday_outbox,wednesday_outbox,thursday_outbox,friday_outbox,saturday_outbox,sunday_outbox

aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg = outbox_week(address,password,outbox,d)

bar_chart = pygal.Bar()
bar_chart.title = 'Weekly Email Analysis'
bar_chart.x_labels =     ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday')
bar_chart.add('Received', [a,b,c,d,e,f,g])
bar_chart.add('Sent',[aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg])
bar_chart.render_to_file('honey4.svg')
```

Comment: The code is not correctly indented. It's important to fix that when asking about Python. It's also not clear if you are looking for a code review, or just the one specific question in your description. Please clarify

Comment: Thanks for commenting, Done with both the issues you specified. Please let me know If my question is fine now.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I am going to make numerous references to [Python's style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). If you've adopted a different guide, you should mention it in the question; if you haven't adopted any, adopt this one. Following a consistent, conventional coding guide makes your code much easier for others to read.

---

Your imports are in the wrong order. This may seem like a minor thing, but it's useful to at least clarify visually which are third-party libraries, and alphabetical order makes it easier to scan for a given library:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import email
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL 

import pygal
```

I've also removed several you *aren't actually using*.

---

Constants should be named in `UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`:

```
ADDRESS = '<Your Email>'
PASSWORD = '<password>'
...
```

---

What exactly does:

```
d = 6
```

mean? I cannot figure out why you're using it at all, and note that you replace it with whatever `inbox_week` returns anyway, so by the time you call `outbox_week` you're actually passing Thursday's inbox count.

At the very least add a comment explaining *why* `d` is `6`, or better yet **use a name that makes it clear**. In this case, it looks like it's supposed to be the number of days, so `DAYS = 6` would be better.

---

The whole `<Weekday>_Tuple`, `<Weekday>_List` thing is completely bewildering, not least because the tuples are constants (again, `UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`, please) and should therefore be declared once, rather than redefined every time *either function* (for, in defiance of the Redundancy Department of Redundancy, you've repeated this code twice) gets called. I don't understand:

- why you're creating the lists and the tuples **at all**, when you don't seem to care about building a list of emails (in fact, you put *the tuple*, rather than the email, into the list!)
- why you would create a tuple `('M', 'o', 'n')` to compare to the first three characters of the date, rather than just comparing the string `main_date[:3] == 'Mon'`; and
- why you don't use `elif`, even though there's no way more than one comparison can be true so you're just wasting cycles testing them.

Also, a minor style point, but the parentheses in e.g. `if (Date_Tuple == Tuesday_Tuple):` are redundant.

Rather than create multiple separate variables, and making pointless lists of tuples, why not a list `[mon_count, tue_count, ..., sun_count]`, or a dictionary `{'Mon': mon_count, ...}`? You could even use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which will do most of the work for you.

---

In another breach of DRYness, note that your two functions are identical, except that they access different mailboxen. Why not make a single function, and specify the mailbox to use? In fact, I note that `inbox` and `outbox` are parameters to the function, *despite* being global constants, which doesn't make much sense. I would split this into more, smaller functions, each with an explanatory [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

---

Finally, the chart-writing bit seems OK, but I would be inclined to wrap that in a function too. You should generally have as little code as possible running at the top level of your script, preferring instead to define a specific entry point (conventionally called `main`) and calling it when the script is run directly with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This makes it easier to `import` your functionality elsewhere later, without running it unnecessarily.

---

Here's an alternative, making the changes I've suggested.

> **Note**: I haven't been able to test it, but it should do exactly what the original did.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta 
import email
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL 

import pygal

ADDRESS = '...'
PASSWORD = '...'

SERVER = 'imap.gmail.com'
INBOX = 'INBOX'
OUTBOX = '[Gmail]/Sent Mail'

DAYS = ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')

def access_mail_server(server, address, password):
    """Connect to the specified mail server and log in."""
    mail = IMAP4_SSL(server)
    mail.login(address, password)
    return mail

def list_mailbox_content(mail, since):
    """Get a list of IDs for all mail in the current mailbox."""
    _, data = mail.uid('search', None, '(SENTSINCE {})'.format(since))
    return data[0].split()

def fetch_message(mail, num):
    """Fetch a message from the current mailbox."""
    _, data = mail.uid('fetch', num, '(RFC822)')
    return email.message_from_string(data[0][1])

def one_week_ago():
    """Get the date from one week ago in the required format."""
    return (date.today()-timedelta(days=6)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

def mailbox_counts(mail, mailbox):
    """Get the counts of emails by day over the last week."""
    counts = [0 for _ in DAYS]
    mail.select(mailbox)
    for id_ in list_mailbox_content(mail, since=one_week_ago()):
        msg = fetch_message(mail, id_)
        counts[DAYS.index(msg['Date'][:3])] += 1
    return counts

def graph_activity(mail, mailboxes):
    """Graph the last week's mail activity."""
    bar_chart = pygal.Bar()
    bar_chart.title = 'Weekly Email Analysis'
    bar_chart.x_labels = DAYS
    for title, mailbox in mailboxes:
        bar_chart.add(title, mailbox_counts(mail, mailbox))
    bar_chart.render_to_file('honey4.svg')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph_activity(
        access_mail_server(SERVER, ADDRESS, PASSWORD),
        [('Received', INBOX), ('Sent', OUTBOX)],
    )
```

Comment: "The whole <Weekday>_Tuple, <Weekday>_List thing is completely bewildering" - it really is. And to go to the effort of naming them monday_x, tuesday_x, ... and then assign them all to variables a,b,c,d,e,f,g and aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg...

Comment: It is throwing errors:                                                                     Traceback (most recent call last):                                                         File "hello21.py", line 57, in <module>
[('Received', INBOX), ('Sent', OUTBOX)],)
File "hello21.py", line 51, in graph_activity
bar_chart.add(title, mailbox_counts(mail, mailbox))
File "hello21.py", line 42, in mailbox_counts
counts[DAYS.index(msg['Date'][:3])] += 1
ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple

Comment: @arshpreet then check what `msg['Date'][:3]` actually is. The nice thing about making the code more modular like this is that you can test each function separately, and easily work out what inputs they take and what output that results in.